# How can I get old browsers?(for testing)

Tags: testing, browser, windows-7

How can I get specific old browsers: Firefox 2.0, Internet Explorer 6, Netscape 9.0.0.6 and Opera 3

I have the operating system, Windows 7 and I want the old browsers to work with Windows 7.

I want the old browsers to test code. Like CSS, JavaScript and some of the HTML tags.

Comment: For IE you can get ie6-11 here (http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)  --pure virtual machines. for other browsers - versions - I dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firefox 2.0.0.1](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/2.0.0.1/), [Netscape 9.0.0.6](http://download.cnet.com/Netscape-Navigator/3000-2356_4-10145004.html) and [Opera 3](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/win/362/english/) are available for download and *should* work on Windows 7, but for Internet Explorer 6, you'll need to [run a virtual machine with Windows XP or Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6).